# Price Set Option still publically visible when visibility set to 'Admin'

Tags: civievent, price-sets

Civi 5.26.1/Drupal 7.72

When I added an option 'Complimentary' to a pre-existing price set with an amount of '0.00' and set visibility to 'Admin', the option was still visible to anonymous users. Testing, I find that setting the 'Admin' option makes no difference to the existing options either.

The 'edit event participants' permission is switched off for anonymous users.

Could this be because the price set is already in use? Any similar experiences or hints for a work around?
[image: Option details]
[image: Registration Screen]

Comment: Are you able to replicate this on the demo server?  https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: Yes, it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Your second screenshot shows that you're logged in as admin, the admin only fee option will still be visible to admins on the event registration page.
The admin only option won’t be available if you visit this page when not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

This belongs as a comment, but I'm bending the rules because I wanted to include screenshots.

I was unable to replicate this.  See my attached screenshots from a demo site.  The first screenshot is while logged in as an admin, the second is as an anonymous user on the same page.  Since you're able to replicate this on the demo server, we must be setting up the page differently.  Could you please edit your question to detail the exact steps you took to set this up?  Or perhaps link to a video?

#### As admin

[image]

#### As anonymous

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I realise now that I wasn't clear in my initial description of the problem. I have three discrete choices, so have set these up as multiple options of a single 'radio' field, not as separate price fields. It is when one of the radio fields is set as 'Admin' that it remains publically visible.

Comment: My select box above is configured as you described.  I just added a radio button price field, in case it was specific to radio buttons.  I've updated my screenshots above; you can see I don't experience what you're describing.  It would help to have a video or screenshots of your setup.

Comment: I've added a couple of screenshots form the demo site. Thanks.

Comment: As Anil points out above - your screenshot is while logged in as an administrative user.  Can you post a screenshot showing the same result as an anonymous user?

Comment: Embarassingly, as you point out, I was still logged into the demo database. When I used the demo link in a different, logged-out, browser there was no issue. However, my live site still has the problem I originally described, tested in a fresh logged-out browser session. It might also be worth noting that this affects multiple events on the same site.

Comment: @Bryan If the problem isn't replicable on the demo site, it's most likely that there's something specific to your installation.  I don't believe there are any changes to this code between 5.26 and 5.28beta.  You might want to see if you have any custom templates or extensions that might be affecting this.  You might also try using an extension like [civicrm_groupprice](https://github.com/tadpolecc/civicrm_groupprice) as an alternative.  I personally won't use any extension that overrides core files (which this one does) but if you have an urgent issue, you can use it now and fix later.

Comment: Thanks, that woeked. Understand your position on core mods, but the groupprice ext helped me out of a hole.